# How to delete blank row

Tags: j

I saved my data into csv format, but the csv file contains quite a lot blank rows.

How can I delete blank rows? like from csv?

```
1   7   5.329618927 5.678765376
2   7   3.364469002 4.176536709
3   7   4.214949544 7.205212347
4   7   3.324136778 8.935188439
5   7   4.746355556 3.89335459



1   8   5.312160001 5.65157164
2   8   3.378701171 4.175205323
3   8   4.202770433 7.216973641
4   8   3.32496778  8.924379077
5   8   4.744037125 3.891049294
```

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: Please provide the simplest code that reproduces the issue. My suspicion is that you're writing multi-dimensional data, but I really haven't worked much with writing CSV files.

Comment: Why negative vote on my answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Reading file with content shown

Assuming that the text above is an example of the contents of your file that you are wanting to import (multiple spaces between fields and some blank lines, then I'd probably import it as follows (note that this isn't really a csv file):

```
   ]Dat=: cut;._2 freads 'myfile.txt'
┌─┬─┬───────────┬───────────┐
│1│7│5.329618927│5.678765376│
├─┼─┼───────────┼───────────┤
│2│7│3.364469002│4.176536709│
├─┼─┼───────────┼───────────┤
...
├─┼─┼───────────┼───────────┤
│ │ │           │           │
├─┼─┼───────────┼───────────┤
│1│8│5.312160001│5.65157164 │
├─┼─┼───────────┼───────────┤
...
├─┼─┼───────────┼───────────┤
│5│8│4.744037125│3.891049294│
└─┴─┴───────────┴───────────┘
   Dat -. (4 # a:)  NB. Dat without items consisting of 4 empty boxes
┌─┬─┬───────────┬───────────┐
│1│7│5.329618927│5.678765376│
├─┼─┼───────────┼───────────┤
...
├─┼─┼───────────┼───────────┤
│5│8│4.744037125│3.891049294│
└─┴─┴───────────┴───────────┘
   _999 ". > Dat -. (4 # a:)  NB. unbox and convert to numeric
1 7 5.32962 5.67877
...
5 8 4.74404 3.89105
```

You can do this as one line:

```
   ]Dat=: _999 ". > -.&(4 # a:) cut;._2 freads 'myfile.txt'
1 7 5.32962 5.67877
2 7 3.36447 4.17654
3 7 4.21495 7.20521
4 7 3.32414 8.93519
5 7 4.74636 3.89335
1 8 5.31216 5.65157
2 8  3.3787 4.17521
3 8 4.20277 7.21697
4 8 3.32497 8.92438
5 8 4.74404 3.89105
```

### Reading/writing csv file

If you have some data you want to save/read as a csv file then the [`tables/csv` addon](http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Addons/tables/csv) will help.

```
   load 'tables/csv'
   Dat writecsv jpath '~temp/myfile.csv'  NB. write to J's temp folder
290
   readcsv jpath '~temp/myfile.csv'
┌─┬─┬───────────┬───────────┐
│1│7│5.329618927│5.678765376│
├─┼─┼───────────┼───────────┤
│2│7│3.364469002│4.176536709│
├─┼─┼───────────┼───────────┤
...
├─┼─┼───────────┼───────────┤
│5│8│4.744037125│3.891049294│
└─┴─┴───────────┴───────────┘
   makenum readcsv jpath '~temp/myfile.csv'
1 7 5.32962 5.67877
2 7 3.36447 4.17654
3 7 4.21495 7.20521
4 7 3.32414 8.93519
5 7 4.74636 3.89335
1 8 5.31216 5.65157
2 8  3.3787 4.17521
3 8 4.20277 7.21697
4 8 3.32497 8.92438
5 8 4.74404 3.89105
```

The addon will automatically reshape arrays of more than 2 dimensions to 2 dimensions so that should not cause any blank lines. If you still have blank lines it is probably best to understand why they are being created and prevent them being written. If you still need to remove them, then the technique shown above will work.

Comment: `(-. a: #~ {:@$) cut;._2 freads 'myfile.txt'` will work for files with any number of fields.

Answer (score 0):

Try following to read input.csv file with blank lines:

```
import csv
with open ('input.csv') as csvfile:
    # READ ALL LINES: 
    csvlines = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

    # REMOVE BLANK LINES:
    csvlines = [x for x in csvlines if len(x) > 0]  

    # PRINT EACH LINE: 
    for onerow in csvlines:
        print(onerow)
```

Output:

```
['1   7   5.329618927 5.678765376']
['2   7   3.364469002 4.176536709']
['3   7   4.214949544 7.205212347']
['4   7   3.324136778 8.935188439']
['5   7   4.746355556 3.89335459']
['1   8   5.312160001 5.65157164']
['2   8   3.378701171 4.175205323']
['3   8   4.202770433 7.216973641']
['4   8   3.32496778  8.924379077']
['5   8   4.744037125 3.891049294']
```

Comment: I didn't vote, sir. Maybe someone vote it for not using J?? 
I just gave you positive to neutralize your answer. 
Thank you for answering my question though. 
It would be useful if I use python in future. = ]